# In Android Studio - NDK, I need to call c++ functions that are not supported by NDK, how to do that?

Tags: c++, android-ndk, hardware, qualcomm

I have been struggling with this problem for 1 week, 18 hours daily, and after I lost all my hopes, I decided to ask your help.

I need to call some c++ functions that are found already in android core, but those functions are not public to NDK and are not supported.

Example of those .c files and functions:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/qcom/audio/+/marshmallow-dr1.5-dev/msm8909/hal/audio_hw.c

As you can see, those are already integrated and found in android source code , for some devices , and I need a way to be able to call those functions from Android Studio , NDK.

I have tried to find resources for this but I couldn't succeed in anything yet. I also have tried to export .so library for those functions needed from qualcom directly, but apparently this will not work too.

I know that those functions may not be supported in all android devices, I am aware of this, and I wil be differentiating them, but at a start point I need to be able to use those c++ files and their functions in a correct way.

Please if you can tell me how or give me a way to be able to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: I found [4](http://androidxref.com/source/search?q=%23define+LOG_TAG+%22audio_hw_primary%22&project=device) "audio_hw.c" file usages in android sources, and, for example [this](http://androidxref.com/source/xref/device/asus/grouper/audio/) project has an "Android.mk" file ([Android.mk manual](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk.html)). So I think you should copy this directory, build a shared library and include it in your project. But that's my guess, I don't know for sure, just hope it will help

Comment: If you really struggled with this as long as you claim, do me a personal favor: when you found a solution, go home, take a shower, eat and get a full night of sleep. And only then, write code that will one day end up on my device.

Comment: @sfk92fksdf , thank you so much for your reply, this folder seems to be for asus platform, but you have mentioned something that could shed me light, do you mean that any codes I find with Android.mk , I can integrate them in my project? and if yes, for example what should I do to use this: http://androidxref.com/source/xref/device/asus/grouper/audio/

Comment: @ChrisM in my first link there's two "samsung" platforms, one "panda" and one "ti" so whichewer you choose. I think you should copy all folder with all files (Android.mk, audio_hw.c, audio_route.c, audio_route.h) to your project, then use copied "Android.mk" file to build local library (I didn't found where it builds in android sources, but seems like it should be [there](http://androidxref.com/source/xref/build/core/main.mk)), then in your project add builder library to project, add includes to your sources (for example `"#include audio_route.h"`) and call library functions from your code

Comment: @sfk92fksdf, thank you again for your help. I have managed to create a project, create my own CPP files, and from them generate .so library successfully. From command nm.exe -D , I can see my JAVA_ com_etc functions, and am able to load this library in mainActivity.java and call those functions. Now back to our headers needed, I have added them to my project too, but I got lot of errors functions not found like: <utils/Log.h> ,  <cutils/properties.h> , #include <media/AudioRecord.h>. Should I solve all those errors manually before being able to use them?

Comment: It's more than just that not all devices are guaranteed to have this. Any time a device takes an update it might disappear.

Comment: @ChrisM, I guess so